# How to get "sout" shorthand to work in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: java, sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, hotkeys

I am trying to get the "sout" shorthand to work in Sublime Text 3 for Java. In vscode and other editors typing "sout + [tab]" will fill in "System.out.println". When I try this in Sublime Text it instead prints "southPane".

Comment: "other editors"? That sounds like an oddly specific expansion mechanism. Is this something that's actually pervasive or a VSCode-specific thing that you're trying to port to Sublime?

Comment: I have used it in Netbeans, Eclipse, and IntelliJ as well. Maybe it is a more specific feature than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that can be done via a [snippet](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/snippets.html) or a [completion](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/completions.html);
both can do this but which you use depends largely on the complexity of the text you want to insert and how many you have.

The main difference is that a `snippet` is a XML based format where each file contains a single completion whereas a `sublime-completions` file is JSON formatted file that can contain many completions at once. Additionally, all snippets are automatically added to the command palette and made available only in files to which they apply.

Thus the XML based snippet is good for larger stretches of code (e.g. blocks) or for any text that needs to contain characters that would be a pain to encode as JSON, whereas the JSON based completions are favored for shorter sequences of text, since you can pack more of them into a file.

To demonstrate a snippet, use `Tools > Developer > New Snippet` to generate a stub, then replace the stub with this content and save it as a file in the default offered location (your `User` package) as a `sublime-snippet` file; the name doesn't matter, but the extension does:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
System.out.println($0);
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>sout</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.java</scope>
</snippet>
```

This says that in a Java file the abbreviation `sout`<kbd>Tab</kbd> will expand out to the text `System.out.println();` with the cursor left inside the parenthesis.

Alternately, create a file with the following content and save it in your `User` package as a `sublime-completions` file (name doesn't matter, only extension, and you can use `Preferences > Browse Packages` to find the `User` package`:

```json
{
    "scope": "source.java",

    "completions": [
        { "trigger": "sout", "contents": "System.out.println($0);" },
    ]
}
```

This does the same as the above example, but the file is smaller, and you can include multiple items in it, say for example by also adding:

```json
        { "trigger": "serr", "contents": "System.err.println($0);" },
```